# Advice for indicating sources in tables

Tags: academic-writing, citations

I'm writing a thesis about the Accords by the Basel Committee on Banking Supervision (BCBS).

If I put a table exactly from the Accords, I write in the table note "Source: BCBS (year)".

If I start from a table of the source but add something mine, I write in the table note that I started from BCBS (year) and I added something.

But if I take a table from the source and only change the order of the rows, to group the elements in a different way, or if I merge two tables from the source into one, without modifying the elements, should I write "Source: based on BCBS (year)" or is "Source: BCBS (year)" enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do change the content, I would suggest using "Adapted from: BCBS (year)".

Answer (score 2):

I think that as long as you only change the formatting of the table and none of its contents, "Source: BCBS (year)" would be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and if I change a bit the content?